# Is the flexible plastic tube that is connected to a handheld shower head called "a shower hose"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

[image]

It seems that dictionaries often relate "**a hose**" as a long tube for watering garden or putting out fire as shown in the above picture.

My bathroom has a shower that look that the picture below.

[image]

Its handheld shower head is connected to a flexible plastic tube which helps you to move the shower easily.

Is that flexible plastic tube called "**a shower hose**"?

Comment: Why not just google **shower hose** and restrict the results to **images**? Actually, the relevant information is just as clearly presented if you restrict the search to **shopping**.

Comment: Flexible shower head and **hose**. However, we actually just say: Yesterday, I bought a flexible shower head and the hose part is understood. We don't say shower hose. We'd **say** the hose connected to the shower head, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  That is called a shower hose - You might need the specific term if you are buying one. It would be very rare to need to refer to this specifically in other contexts.